# 'ifinite' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, compilation, shogun

I'm trying to compile shogun toolbox and I'm getting this fault

```
    C:/shogun-3.0.0/shogun-3.0.0/src/shogun/../shogun/mathematics/Math.h: In static
    member function 'static int shogun::CMath::is_finite(double)':
    C:/shogun-3.0.0/shogun-3.0.0/src/shogun/../shogun/mathematics/Math.h:1255:20: er
    ror: 'ifinite' was not declared in this scope
    return ifinite(f);
```

function itself looks like this.

```
        inline static int is_finite(double)
        {      
        #if defined(isfinite) && !defined(SUNOS)
        return ifinite(f);
        #else
        return finite(f);
        #endif
        }
```

I believe similar is described here: http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1768, but I'm not sure as I don't include cmath. Any idea what it can be?

Comment: Shouldn't the function's name be `isfinite` and not `ifinite`?

Comment: Are you sure to not include cmath?

Comment: Probably it's a typo... Correct it to `isfinite`.

Comment: I think it is unlikely that OP typed both the source and the error messages and made the some typo in three places. This would have to be an error in the source. But it is not in the 3.0.0 source that I just downloaded. So how did it get there?

Answer (score 2):

Function is `isfinite`, not `ifinite`.

You don't include `<cmath>` but according to Shogun source [here](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/blob/d4599786c90626434de9be7e0d689dcba016f4be/src/shogun/mathematics/Math.cpp), it does include both `<cmath>` and `<math.h>` in the wrong order:

```
#include <shogun/base/SGObject.h>
#include <shogun/lib/common.h>
#include <cmath>                             <<<<<<
#include <shogun/mathematics/Math.h>
#include <shogun/mathematics/lapack.h>
#include <shogun/io/SGIO.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>                            <<<<<<
```

So you are supposed to use `std::isfinite`.

Comment: changing the order in Math.cpp didnt help.

Comment: changing all calls in math.h like

Comment: //if (!CMath::is_finite(p))
            if (!std::is_finite(p)
            return q;
            //if (!CMath::is_finite(q))
            if (!std::is_finite

Comment: dont help also. Sorry, dont know how to add the code in the comment,

Comment: There is no "wrong order" in which `<cmath>` and `<math.h>` can be included. Usually, `<cmath>` includes `<math.h>`, so there can never be a conflict anyways...

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded shogun-3.0.0 from [here](http://shogun-toolbox.org/new/37), and there is no occurrence of the string “ifinite” anywhere in the source. The definition of `is_finite` in `Math.h` is:

```
        /// checks whether a float is finite
        inline static int is_finite(double f)
        {
#if defined(isfinite) && !defined(SUNOS)
            return isfinite(f);
#else
            return finite(f);
#endif
        }
```

If the errors and source text you entered into the question are correct, perhaps the sources you have were corrupted. You should download the source and try again.